# Accessing extra data passed while calling a celery task

Tags: django, celery, django-celery

I have task that I'm starting with `apply_async` such that I can pass extra data. However I'm having trouble accessing this data in the `celery signals`. For instance this an example of the task, how I'm calling it and `task_prerun` signal.

```
@task
def export_olx(user_id, course_id, language):
    pass

export_olx.apply_async(args=(user_id, course_id, language), **{'some_key':'some_value'})

@task_prerun.connect(sender=export_olx)
def export_olx_prerun(sender, **kwargs):
    pass
```

Inside my `task_prerun` signal I'm able to access the args using `sender.request.args`, however when I try using `sender.request.kwargs` I get an empty dictionary instead of the extra data I passed `{'some_key':'some_value'}`

Any help on how I can access this data will be much appreciated thank you.

Comment: Did you try `def export_olx_prerun(sender, *args, **kwargs)`

Comment: Yes I have just tried it and it's not working. Currently I'm passing a headers dictionary into apply_async then accessing it using `sender.request.headers` in `export_olx_prerun`.

Comment: Idk, I never used it the way you try. I always do it with `(signal=None, sender=None, task_id=None, task=None, args=None, kwargs=None)` and in the prerun handler i am explicitly checking task.name.

Comment: Does this work is `kwarg` was not explicitly defined as an `argument` of the `task`?